# Como inibir textbox mas exibir dados de ID

Tags: c#, winforms

Gostaria que o TextBox ID fosse inibido (não quero invisível) porém exibisse dados do ID que é gravado (autoincrement) no banco de dados.

Estou utilizando o Visual Studio 2015 Community.

Exemplo: eu faço o cadastro de um cliente sem colocar o ID, mas quando fosse visualizar este cliente, o ID seria exibido no textox ID.

Comment: coloca ele como ReadOnly apenas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trocando a propriedade `Enabled` para `false`, ou a propriedade `ReadOnly` para `true`.

Na maioria dos componentes, trocar o valor de `ReadOnly` mantém o controle com a mesma aparência, porém impede que algum valor seja inserido. Em contrapartida, o `Enabled` mostra o controle com uma aparência levemente diferente. Mas isso **sempre** vai variar conforme o sistema operacional, no form abaixo o primeiro TextBox está normal, o segundo está com `Enabled` como `false` e o terceiro está com `ReadOnly` ativo.

[image: Form com três textboxes]

Você pode fazer isso no código, no construtor do form

```
public MeuForm()
{
    InitializeComponents();
    txtId.Enabled = false;
}
```

Ou na janela de propriedades, pelo Visual Studio.

Comment: Adendo: No caso do `TextBox`, com o `ReadOnly` ele fica com uma cor de fundo mais escura (que pode ser alterada). Basicamente a diferença entre as duas propriedades é que a `ReadOnly` ainda permite o `Focus` no controle, e o `Enabled` não.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente.. Muito obrigado

Comment: @FabioAragão Não sei se você sabe, mas sempre que uma resposta solucionar seu problema você pode marcá-la como correta usando o **V** do lado esquerdo.

Comment: @LINQ creio já ter feito isso..

Comment: @FabioAragão Ainda não, porque tem que esperar 15 minutos de pergunta pra poder marcar.

Comment: @LINQ consegui.. marquei a resposta... me ajudou bastante aqui. obrigado